# How to enable scrolling in slides for a jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

How do I enable vertical scrolling once I've launched the slideshow in a jupyter notebook ?

If the slides are larger than the window, then they are cut and we cannot see what at the bottom.

I created the slides by simply clicking on the "basic" slides auto generated by jupyter.

Fyi my version is 4.2.3

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just add --SlidesExporter.reveal_scroll=True at the end of the command

as

```
jupyter nbconvert reveal.ipynb --to slides --post serve  --SlidesExporter.reveal_scroll=True
```

Comment: That works great for an entire presentation. Does anyone have suggestion about just making specific slides scrollable?

Answer (score 0):

After trying multiple solutions posted elsewhere, I found that [jupyter2slides](https://github.com/datitran/jupyter2slides) seems to solve this issue. It creates static `html` files that can be vertically scrolled.

- **Step 1**: Clone the git repo using `git clone https://github.com/datitran/jupyter2slides.git`
- **Step 2**: Copy your notebook (`.ipynb`) in `jupyter2slides/static` directory.
- **Step 3**: Execute `python create_slides.py --file static/your_notebook.ipynb` from `jupyter2slides` directory.

Comment: Your answer will be better if you include the steps to show the vertical scrolling in jupyter2slider

Comment: @SudheeshR Now steps included in the answer.